# Как вставить результат выполнения функции в ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Функция:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var cost = $("#cost").val();
  var tmp = "http://site.com/go/<?php echo $this->user->info->username ?>/?transaction=" + name + "&item=" + cost;
  var result = encodeURI(tmp);
  $("#tar1").html(result);
  $("#par1").html(result);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как вставить результат выполнения в a href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[документация по jquery .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var cost = $("#cost").val();
  var tmp = "http://site.com/go/<?php echo $this->user->info->username ?>/?transaction=" + name + "&item=" + cost;
  var result = encodeURI(tmp);
  $("#tar1").html(result);
  $("#par1").html(result);
  return result;
}

$('#someId').attr('href', myFunction());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="someId" href="">ссылка</a>
```